# Calling static members from the super class of a generalizated attribute in Java

Tags: java, oop, templates, static

I must admit that Java is a little messy when working with templates...

As the title explains, i'm trying to use an static member coded on the super class of some generalizated attribute. How can i do this?

For example:

```
class A {
    public static void someAction();
}

class B<T extends A>{ (...) }
```

¿how do i access the A's `someAction()` method in the class B?

Comment: You can try A.someAction() .

Comment: that's right, thanks a lot... now i feel ashamed, the answer was so obvious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do i access A's `someAction()` method from the class B?

Just call

```
A.someAction()
```

It's a static method, so the fact that B's type parameter extends A has no effect whatsoever.

---

If `someAction` should be generic and you want to use B's `<T>` parameter with A, then declare `someAction` with its own type parameter:

```
public static <T> void someAction(.../* use T here maybe */) { ... }
```

and from `B` you can then do

```
A.<T>someAction(...)
```

so that the `<T>` before `someAction` is the same as the `<T extends A>` visible in the body of `B`.

Comment: @Bengalaa, Look at [`Collections.emptySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptySet%28%29).  It's a static method with a type parameter `<T>` and return value `Set<T>`.  If you call `Collections.emptySet()` you get an always-empty `Set<Object>` but if you call `Collections.<String>emptySet()` you get an always-empty `Set<String>`.